# Why does bitwise left shift from numpy give different results on different systems?

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I use bitwise operations from numpy on two different system and get different / inconsistent results. After a bit of investigation I found out that `left_shift` causes the problem. If I do the following:

```
xs = [i for i in range(100)]
np.left_shift(xs, xs)
```

On the first system I get:

```
array([                   0,                    2,                    8,
                         24,                   64,                  160,
                        384,                  896,                 2048,
                       4608,                10240,                22528,
                      49152,               106496,               229376,
                     491520,              1048576,              2228224,
                    4718592,              9961472,             20971520,
                   44040192,             92274688,            192937984,
                  402653184,            838860800,           1744830464,
                 3623878656,           7516192768,          15569256448,
                32212254720,          66571993088,         137438953472,
               283467841536,         584115552256,        1202590842880,
              2473901162496,        5085241278464,       10445360463872,
             21440476741632,       43980465111040,       90159953477632,
            184717953466368,      378231999954944,      774056185954304,
           1583296743997440,     3236962232172544,     6614661952700416,
          13510798882111488,    27584547717644288,    56294995342131200,
         114841790497947648,   234187180623265792,   477381560501272576,
         972777519512027136,  1981583836043018240,  4035225266123964416,
        8214565720323784704, -1729382256910270464, -2882303761517117440,
       -4611686018427387904, -6917529027641081856, -9223372036854775808,
       -9223372036854775808,                   64,                  130,
                        264,                  536,                 1088,
                       2208,                 4480,                 9088,
                      18432,                37376,                75776,
                     153600,               311296,               630784,
                    1277952,              2588672,              5242880,
                   10616832,             21495808,             43515904,
                   88080384,            178257920,            360710144,
                  729808896,           1476395008,           2986344448,
                 6039797760,          12213813248,          24696061952,
                49928994816,         100931731456,         204010946560,
               412316860416,         833223655424,        1683627180032,
              3401614098432])
```

And on the second system I get:

```
array([                   0,                    2,                    8,
                         24,                   64,                  160,
                        384,                  896,                 2048,
                       4608,                10240,                22528,
                      49152,               106496,               229376,
                     491520,              1048576,              2228224,
                    4718592,              9961472,             20971520,
                   44040192,             92274688,            192937984,
                  402653184,            838860800,           1744830464,
                 3623878656,           7516192768,          15569256448,
                32212254720,          66571993088,         137438953472,
               283467841536,         584115552256,        1202590842880,
              2473901162496,        5085241278464,       10445360463872,
             21440476741632,       43980465111040,       90159953477632,
            184717953466368,      378231999954944,      774056185954304,
           1583296743997440,     3236962232172544,     6614661952700416,
          13510798882111488,    27584547717644288,    56294995342131200,
         114841790497947648,   234187180623265792,   477381560501272576,
         972777519512027136,  1981583836043018240,  4035225266123964416,
        8214565720323784704, -1729382256910270464, -2882303761517117440,
       -4611686018427387904, -6917529027641081856, -9223372036854775808,
       -9223372036854775808,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0])
```

So, as you can see, up to a certain points the results become inconsistent. Does any one know what could cause it?

**ADDED**

By "different systems" I mean different computers. The first computer has numpy 1.15.1 and the second one 1.15.2.

Comment: What does "different systems" mean here? Numpy 1.19 vs Numpy 1.21? Win vs Linux? Python2 vs Python3? Dell vs HP?

Comment: BTW, I get the second output Numpy 1.19.4, Python 3.8.

Comment: @Mr.T. I get different results on different computers. Version of numpy are also different. The first one has version 1.15.1 and the second one 1.15.2.

Comment: @Roman I just tried on numpy 1.19 and 1.15.1 -- getting the same results (number 2). Maybe it is machine specific? I skimmed through the numpy microfunctions, but found no clue why this could be happening. Maybe if you provide machine specs (and os bitwidth), it might give some hint?

Comment: With Numpy 1.15.1 in the same environment, I get an output that is neither your first nor the second (ends with 792).

Answer (score 6):

Old versions of NumPy don't define what shift operators do if you try to shift by an amount >= the width of a type. They basically just delegate the semantics to the C shift operators, [for which this is undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7). Depending on hardware and compiler details, pretty much anything could happen (theoretically up to and including crashes, security issues, and arbitrary other misbehavior).

This got [changed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/24b2a2d36a7e8356310cd16dbe60abd9d0e682dc) in 1.18, but your NumPy versions are older than that.

If you want defined behavior, don't try to do shifts like that.